# How to bind values from script and output to Html

Tags: javascript

How to bind json value to script and need a output in html. I try to get the data and image of weather, but no solution. Help me

here is an sample of jquery

```
$(function(){
   $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", {
      q: "select * from json where url=\"http://api.wunderground.com/api/91bbc8aab3ab1f34/geolookup/conditions/q/IN/Chennai.json\"",
      format: "json"
}, function(data) {
   var $content = $("#content")
   if (data.query.results) {
     $content.text(JSON.stringify(data.query.results));
   } else {
      $content.text('no such code: ' + code);
   }

 });
});​
```

code in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
```

the content is div and icon is an image tag

```
<div id="content">
<img id="weather_icon" />
```

when i run the application it takes the data alone . i need the weather images and data from the api.
Please help

Comment: `console.log(data.query.results)` and see what u get in results...

Comment: hi bipen i didnt get the result...would be please help me. I am a beginner in json and jquery

Comment: after `var $content = $("#content")` add `console.log(data)`.. and check in your firbug console.. u should get all the datas inside data object....

Comment: posted the answer.. check it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, was able to display the weather icon.. I modified the jQuery to display the image by setting the url into the image tag. Just dig for the data you want to be displayed in the content div.

```
        $(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", {
            q: "select * from json where url=\"http://api.wunderground.com/api/91bbc8aab3ab1f34/geolookup/conditions/q/IN/Chennai.json\"",
            format: "json"
            }, 
            function(data) {
                // Dig for the data from the JSON object. 
                //  The image URL can be found at: query > results > json > current_location > icon_url
                $('#weather_icon').attr('src', data.query.results.json.current_observation.icon_url);
                //  Do the same for any data you want displayed for the content to be displayed..
            });
    });
```

Comment: About the jQuery, the important line there is:
$('#weather_icon').attr('src', data.query.results.json.current_observation.icon_url);

This line sets the src attribute of the img tag to the data from the json object. I'm quite a beginner in jQuery myself, just google how to put stuffs in a div tag.

Hope I helped :D

Answer (score 0):

According to the fiddle u provided..

I used full to display the city name in `<p id="temp"></p>`.

```
$('#temp').html(data.query.results.json.current_observation.display_location.full);
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SH7Ku/1/

**updated**

here is updated fiddle....with temperature

http://jsfiddle.net/SH7Ku/2/

likewise u can do for rest...

Comment: start using firebug console... that will help u to check the json data returned and will make your job easy...:)  anyways cheers...and start accepting answer..so that other users will start helping you  :) :)